# SQLite can't load data because of an error in App.config file

Tags: c#, sqlite, devexpress

I have a database in SQLite called MiDonations.db in the directory of the application that has a table called tblDonationsList , this table was filled manually with some generic data. When i try to fill a gridcontrol , it returns null.

Update: After removing try and catch , it now shows a message "configuration system failed to initialize"

This is the code i use in DataAccessLayer class

```
 public DataTable Select(string selectStatment, string parameterName = "", byte[] x = null,string id="Default")
    {

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString))
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStatment, con))
            using (var dt = new DataTable())
            {
                if (parameterName != "")
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterName, SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = x;

                }

                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }  
    }
```

the connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\MiDonations.db; Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The code for retrieving data

```
            // Get data and cast it to datatable
            var dt =  new DataAccessLayer().Select($"SELECT * FROM tblDonationsList ");

            // Set datasource in datagridview to datatable
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Remove the `try`/`catch`. Is there any error?

Comment: So, now suppose that your code throws an exception. How do you know this info if you have an exception handler that it's only job is to return null?. It is better to remove it. Or at least write in some log the ex.Message, or display  the ex.Message on your screen. Anything but not as it is now

Comment: updated the code , it  now throws configuration system failed to initialize

Comment: See it? You have some trouble in your config file where the connectionstrings are stored.

Comment: The problem is in .config file. Add it to the question.

Comment: updated the question , i fixed the config file by resetting it but another error showed up "SQL instance can't be found " but i solved it by changing how i connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Resetting the App.config file i was able to fix the "configuration system failed to initialize" but i faced another problem that my application can't find the database , After some searching i figured that the problem is in the DataAccessLayer Class and fixed it by changing

```
 public DataTable Select(string selectStatment, string parameterName = "", byte[] x = null,string id="Default")
{

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString))
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStatment, con))
        using (var dt = new DataTable())
        {
            if (parameterName != "")
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterName, SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = x;

            }

            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }

}
```

to

```
  public DataTable Select(string selectStatment, string parameterName = "", byte[] x = null)
    {

        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString))
        //using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\MiDonations.db; Version=3;"))
        using (var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectStatment, con))
        using (var dt = new DataTable())
        {
            if (parameterName != "")
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterName, DbType.String).Value = x;

            }

            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
new SQLiteConnection("Default")
```

I don't remember it very well, but for SQLConnection I think it used the name of the connection string instead of the whole connection string when passed on the constructor.